# Adding "submit your story idea" to navigation bar

Tags: navigation

We have multiple websites that have similar designs, just for different industries. Recently, to all our sites, we added a series of forms where people can submit photos or information to give us story ideas for different topics. Then we created a landing page at /submit, where we link to all these forms.

We wanted to link to this new landing page in the navigation of our sites. We also wanted to add a link to our contact page from the navigation. So at the end of the navigation bar, we added a menu item called *contact*, with two dropdown items: *contact us*, and *submit a story idea*. Like this:

[image]

Now, we ran into a bit of an issue with [one of our sites](http://snoriderswest.com). Its navigation doesn't quite have room to add the new *contact* item to the navigation menu.

[image]

Now, we're currently redesigning our site, so this will just be a somewhat temporary thing. Therefore, we don't want to re-think the navigation bar at all. We want to keep the *home* link. We also don't want to change the font padding or text size to squeeze it in.

So my question is, where in the current navigation would it make most sense to include these items? No solution will be ideal, but we want to put it in there somewhere.

*Archive* seems like it would make the most sense, as all the other sections have a very specific purpose. Under the *archive* menu, we have three items, a link to read the online magazine, a link to read past email newsletters, and a link to a form where users can subscribe to the print magazine. Possibly under that heading, we could add *contact us* and *submit a story idea*. We could change the name of the heading, but can't really think of a good term to describe all the five items that it would contain. *About* or *about us* was suggested as a very general term, but I figured it might confuse users expecting an *About us* page.

Any thoughts / ideas?

Comment: those navigation menus are pretty frustrating - it disappears unless I carefully move the mouse through the little tiny bubble arrow at the top of the link drop down.

Comment: use this css override to greatly improve the navigation experience  --  `.dropdown-menu { margin: 0 !important; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working within the constraints you are providing, I would suggest:

- shortening the name "Blogs & Columns" to just "Blogs" to make more space.
- shorten "Destinations" to "Places" or something else?

Those two combinations might give you space.

That said, I think you have quite a busy nav bar already, so I'm not sure if it makes sense to try to add this extra element in.

I also wonder why you want to keep "home"? If you have a logo in the top left that links to your home page I don't think you'd need the "home" taking up nav space.

You could also consider other UI elements for this "submit your story" call to action as an alternative to the nav.

Comment: It is a pretty common pattern to put the logo in the upper left corner and have it navigate "home".  if you really can't remove it then perhaps you can turn it into a little square icon of a house?